# How to do logical operation between DataFrame columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'valid': True}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'valid':False}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   a  b  valid
0  1  2   True
1  3  4  False
```

I want to assign `a` column data to a new column if `valid` is True, or assign `b` column data to new column if `valid` is False. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['valid'], df['a'], df['b'])
print (df)
   a  b  valid  new
0  1  2   True    1
1  3  4  False    4
```